# Lista con iconos no se colocan

Tags: html

Tengo una lista que quiero que quede dividida en 2 columnas, para ello, usé este código:

```css
.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  display: flex;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}

#contenido {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="contenido">

  <div style="flex-grow: 10" >
  
    <h1 class="receta">Ingredientes</h1>
    
    <p class="contenido" style="text-align: left">
    
      <div class="ingredientes">
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            2 huevos.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            30 g de mantequilla pomada.
          </p>
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            1 vaso de leche.
          </p>
        
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             30 g de azúcar.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             220 g de harina de trigo
          </p>
                  
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1 trocito de mantequilla.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1/2 cucharadita de levadura química.
          </p>
                  
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
    </p>
  
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero en la web se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es la definicion de tus clases contenido y fila?

Comment: Veo que asignas la clase **columna** a elementos **p** y estos por defecto ocupan el ancho máximo del contenedor en que se encuentran. Y, no muestras los estilos **css** que estás asignando a dicha clase para sugerir un ajuste. Debes sobreescribir el estilo para `p.columna {display : inline-block; }` y ajustar su ancho a 30% o 50% y sus márgenes por defecto (margin), para que se vean alineados.

Comment: Me di cuenta que me faltaba parte del estilo y que por eso salía sin columnas, pero me ocurre otra cosa. Modifico la pregunta

Comment: @Lucía no modifiques la pregunta, si tienes otro detalle puedes realizar otra pregunta y hacer referencia a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo el patrón de tu código solo deberias crear otro  `<div class="fila">` y agregar la tercera etiqueta `<p>` que tienes en el primer `div` de la siguiente forma y cambiar el porcentaje de la clase columna por  `width: 50%;` para que abarque toda la página.

```css
.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}

#contenido {
 background-color:none;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:15px;
 margin-top:7px;
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="contenido">

  <div style="flex-grow: 10" >
  
    <h1 class="receta">Ingredientes</h1>
    
    <p class="contenido" style="text-align: left">
    
      <div class="ingredientes">
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            2 huevos.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            30 g de mantequilla pomada.
          </p>   
        
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             30 g de azúcar.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             220 g de harina de trigo
          </p>
                  
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1 trocito de mantequilla.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1/2 cucharadita de levadura química.
          </p>
                  
        </div>
         <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            1 vaso de leche.
          </p>
                  
        </div>
        
        
      
      </div>
      
    </p>
  
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu html en realidad tienes definidas 3 columnas, puedes usar el siguiente estilo:

```
<style>
.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  flex: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Ejemplo:

```css
.fila {
  display: flex;
}

.columna {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="contenido">

  <div style="flex-grow: 10" >
  
    <h1 class="receta">Ingredientes</h1>
    
    <p class="contenido" style="text-align: left">
    
      <div class="ingredientes">
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            2 huevos.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            30 g de mantequilla pomada.
          </p>
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
            1 vaso de leche.
          </p>
        
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             30 g de azúcar.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             220 g de harina de trigo
          </p>
                  
        </div>
      
        <div class="fila">
        
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1 trocito de mantequilla.
          </p>
          
          <p class="columna">
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i>
             1/2 cucharadita de levadura química.
          </p>
                  
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
    </p>
  
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```